# CSS position on top of everything

Tags: css

I have a `fab-menu` that I want it to be on top of data table buttons see screenshot (relative position):

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.fab-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

I have tried position absolute which worked but the `fab-menu` buttons are misplaced. See screenshot (absolute position):

[image]

CSS of data table scroll wrap:

```
.datatable-scroll-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

PS : if i remove `overflow-x: auto;` the buttons will appear on top but the table scroll bar will not show up if i resize the page

Comment: what you are really trying to achieve ? please provide more of your code

Comment: You have false assumptions about how z-index works. It's far more complicated than you think. Google "z-index stacking context" to get an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under

```
.datatable-scroll-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: .01%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

add the following :

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .datatable-scroll-wrap .dropdown-menu {
        position: absolute!important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .datatable-scroll-wrap {
        overflow: visible;
    }
}
```